# Where I can find "subWalletGuid" for Paytm Wallet Transfer API?

Tags: payment, paytm

I am integrating the Wallet Transfer API of Paytm, which requires **"subWalletGuid"** parameter. As per documentation "This is available on Paytm dashboard" but I am not able to find that?
Can anyone help?[image: From paytm]

Comment: Even i'm trying to do same. are you able to figure out? even paytm dev support not responding.

Answer (score 4):

Paytm is not very clear in their documentation

Wallet transfer API is available **under Paytm payouts** which are only available for **enterprise customers** for which you need to contact them. Very stupid since a user cannot transfer his own Paytm cash via his wallet.

Bank Transfer API or Wallet Transfer API both come under Paytm payout

[image]

Here's the link to the page: https://developer.paytm.com/docs/paytm-payouts/

Comment: there is no dev environment for this?

Comment: @GKV got any info on this?