# Paytm API - how to get subwalletGuid?

Tags: paytm

I have found similar post below 
[Where I can find "subWalletGuid" for Paytm Wallet Transfer API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60168862/where-i-can-find-subwalletguid-for-paytm-wallet-transfer-api)

posting again. How do we get subwalletGuid?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60168862/where-i-can-find-subwalletguid-for-paytm-wallet-transfer-api, Please check the answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

To get the subwalletGuid configured on your MID, you can contact to paytm developer support. You can post the request on contact us section of paytm developer. After this it would be available on paytm dashboard itself.

Comment: I allready created a ticket for paytm developer. till now no one responded, customer care really bad....... I tried to find in my bashboard but i dont see it anywhere, do you know where exactly I can find this guidid? like in profile page or somewhere else?